# File.WriteAllText() not working in Server 2012 with IIS8

Tags: c#, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012, iis-8

Code:

```
string xml = sr.ReadToEnd();
string fileName = Server.MapPath("/") + "XML\\" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".xml";
EventLog.WriteEntry("HCC", "Writing to " + fileName);
File.WriteAllText(fileName, xml);
```

The EventLog entry gets written with the approperiate file name saying it's writing, but no file actually ever gets written.

This is for a web listener, so I don't have the ability to run through the build on the server or locally to try to debug in VB.

I have the file access set to Full Access for the IIS user. What else may I be missing?

Comment: You don't get any exception ?

Comment: Please define "...and it's not working.". We need more details, help us so we can to help you.

Comment: You will get UTF-8 encoding *without* byte-order mark (preamble). That might not be what you want.

Comment: Fixed my original question, sorry for the invalid data before

Comment: @Sam I added more detail.

Comment: why are you using both \\ and / ? 
They should both be the same :)

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm using code from a Git repo. The fileName string seems to be exactly what I need. I could change to `"XML/"` no problem

Comment: @AndrewWilson I would try attaching to the process and debugging, you can attach to a process on a remote machine: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68z0b3.aspx#BKMK_Attach_to_a_process_on_a_remote_computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, it was the IIS_IUSRS permission set that was causing the problems. Even though the Application was running under another user, I assumed it'd use those permissions. I was wrong.

Comment: For the record, it's considered a bad practice to have your web application interact with the file system directly. The better practice would be to mediate the file system access through a service.